# Constant Contact module puts subscribe checkbox on every user profile page

Tags: 7, users

So, we are using the Constant Contact module to allow users to sign up for newsletters on our website. In the admin pages the module provides a 'Subscribe Method' option that let's you specify how users opt-in to the newsletter feature. We are using 'checkbox'.

This is all fine, except that we are also using user profiles, with multiple categories. When a user goes to edit his or her account details this 'subscribe' checkbox is appearing on every single category page, even when its totally irrelevant.

Is there some way we would be able to hide / remove this field from displaying anywhere other than the user's 'account' page?

Comment: This sounds like a bug with the module.  Has it been reported in the module's issue queue?

Comment: I agree; I should probably do that soon!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this same issue.  It is due to a bug in the module.  I have submitted an issue [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2744287) and have attached a patch which fixes the bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the block module enabled - try removing it.

If you like how the block module displays the checkbox information - its for new "newsletter signups" - restrict it's view.

1 - Go to - admin/structure/block/manage/constant_contact/1/configure
2 - Head all the way to the bottom for visibility settings.
3 - add which nodes/pages you'd like it to be visible in. You can use * as a wildcard.
4 - Save settings.
5 - Save blocks.

Check if that works for you.

Comment: Not quite there. What you're talking about described how to control the blocks allowing users to signup appears on pages on the website. We need to control how the signup box appears in the user registration page, which isn't controlled via a block.